# NotificationManager in SherlockFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-notifications

My code is for Notification in my App that use SherlockFragment:

**Code:**

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

**Error:**

> ERROR: Create constant NOTIFICATION_SERVICE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getSystemService()` and `NOTIFICATION_SERVICE` are defined on `Context`. `Activity` inherits from `Context`, but `SherlockFragment` does not.

Change your code to:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```